Pycharm wont recognise standard libraries
I have been using Pycharm for months now on various learning projects.  I am working through another one and I simply cant get it to find the standard libraries.  If I try to use import random I just get the underline and an error on running code (seems to be looking locally).
It seems to be an issue with not finding an interpreter but, having tried to follow several 'how to' guides I just cant get it to stick.  I have reinstalled a few times now trying combinations including importing the VS code settings.
I'm almost certain that this used to work but may have changed when another tutorial set up a project space ... I thought that a vanilla installation would fix it but nope.
Is there an idiot proof way to fix this - I can get to menus of interpreters but no idea what to select or how to find the base python interpreter (my project folder is pathed to my D drive, whereas the installation is on C if that matters).
I have looked at the posts that seem to address this and either the interface has changed or I have a weird system but I cant get it to work.
I have tried navigating to c:/mysys64/mingw64/bin/pthon.exe etc but no joy.

Does import sys work?  If so, show us the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)

Do the scripts run properly?  That is, is it only the editor that is complaining?

It seems like if you name your file random.py and call import random, you will get weird errors.
Renaming the file has now allowed the import to work.
